# React Security Concerns: Restricted pages in App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am relatively new to web-developing as well as using React.js and wanted to double-check on some security concerns:

### Authentication

Assuming part of my app should not be accessible for unauthenticated users and I implement this by calling for example AWS Cognito and a conditional render:

```
{Auth ? <userPanel/> : <smthElse/>}
```

Is there any scope for client-side manipulation i.e, is there a way to access the userPanel component despite being rejected by Cognito?

### Authorisation

Furthermore, if I have different user groups (user, admin etc), what would be a safe way to restrict different parts of the App? Some options i have come up with so far:

1. Same as above, with directly calling the Cognito API and a conditional render
2. Maybe there is way to make the Redux state temper-proof and to use it in combination with private react-router-dom routes
3. Use private routes in combination with direct calls to the Cognito API

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Client-side authentication/authorisation is impossible and should be avoided.

The front-end should not be bundled with any sensitive data.
Secure your API endpoints instead, so that even if users edit the source to render the component/page, they will not see any sensitive data rendered unless they are authorised.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing on client side is tamper proof. I think your solution is fine as long as you're performing a back-end validation as well, before rendering the page.

If you're really concerned that this might be changed from the client side, I would suggest setting up an entirely different route for authenticated vs non-authenticated users